# No module named graphviz but graphviz is right there

Tags: python, graphviz

I am trying to use some python script and I got

```
from graphviz import Digraph
ImportError: No module named graphviz
```

Ok, so I do

```
sudo apt-get install -y graphviz libgraphviz-dev
```

and then I got

```
graphviz is already the newest version (2.40.1-2).
graphviz set to manually installed.
libgraphviz-dev is already the newest version (2.40.1-2).
libgraphviz-dev set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 205 not upgraded.
```

if it is already installed why "no module"??

Comment: You have installed `graphviz` the binary package (which provides e.g. the `dot` command), but you have not yet installed the `graphviz` Python module. You probably want `apt install python3-graphviz`, assuming that you're using Python 3.

Comment: and in the case of python 2?

Comment: It looks like that package doesn't run under Python 2.